# Automatically executing dependency:build-classpath in maven

Tags: java, maven, plugins, pom.xml

I am literally trying to do exactly this:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#The_dependency:build-classpath_mojo

What's amazing is that after finding an explicit example of exactly what I want Maven to do.. I still can't get it to work.

From the command line, I can run ...
mvn -Dmdep.outputFile=classpath.txt dependency:build-classpath
... which does indeed produce a file called classpath.txt with the information I'd like.

I would like to be able to issue a command like "mvn compile" and have the production of this classpath.txt file be a part of that process. The example provided at the link above associates it with generate-sources, which to my understanding should suffice.

When executing a command like "mvn compile" with this pom snippet below, nothing regarding the build-classpath goal seems to execute.

```
<build>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>      

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>

        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>

     </plugin>

     <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8</version>
      <executions>
       <execution>
        <id>build-classpath</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>build-classpath</goal>
        </goals>
         <configuration>
            <outputFile>myfile.txt</outputFile>
            <mdep.outputFile>myFile1.txt</mdep.outputFile>
            <ihavenoidea>whatgoeshere</ihavenoidea>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

And here is what I end up with:

```
$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building someproj 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ someproj ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ someproj ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.600s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jan 31 14:05:29 CST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/156M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ ls 
bin     html        log     pom.xml     resources   sql     src     target      test-output wwwroot
```

Comment: StackExchange is amazing. I know this because moments after posting my problem, I solved it on my own. :|

Removing the "PluginManagement" element solves the issue, but I'm not entirely sure why. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please add an answer to your question and accept it as the answer.  That way, people searching for your problem will find your solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin definition is inside `<pluginManagement>`, which means that when you will declare a "real" execution of that plugin inside a pom that has this pom as parent (or this pom itself), it will use that configuration.

This is generaly a good idea to use `<pluginManagement>` when a common configuration has to be applied on multiple execution, through multiple modules in the same global project.

Here, I would personally keep the compiler plugin inside `<pluginManagement>`, as you probably always want that plugin to be configured like this, but I woul move the dependency-plugin inside the `<plugins>` section (outside the `<pluginManagement>` section, well yes, this can be confusive...)

Comment: That was exactly it. pluginManagement was making maven treat my addition more like a template, apparently for child poms.
There is also another similar thread here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483180/maven-what-is-pluginmanagement

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of `<pluginManagement>` as a kind of template.  It's often used in parent POMs to define a common configuration.  Only plugins in `<build><plugins>` are included in the build.

That said, Maven does do some "magic" depending on the packaging type.  I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12691273/944849).